# another way of saying "being of"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I am looking for a way to replace the word "being" in the phrase "being of poor character".  My instructor is very adamant that we not use being unless it is used as a noun.  In this particular case, I am having trouble replacing it.

Comment: I guess it's not his fault (being we all gotta eat! :), but your "instructor" is in the wrong job.

Comment: Can you give the full sentence?

Comment: So how would your instructor say _Being a stubborn man, he passed his prejudices to his students_?

Comment: *As he was of poor character, my instructor asked us not to use to use the word **being** except as a noun.*  (Of course one of my English professors admonished me for using *as* meaning 'because' *as* it can lead to confusion.)

Comment: For the particular sentence.... "Possessing poor character"

Answer (score 2):

That's because your instructor is wrong. You definitely need a new instructor. That sentence is absolutely fine.

> He, being of poor character and strong rashness, insulted some gang members and was beaten up.

Answer (score 1):

Your instructor is wrong, of course, but I understand what he or she is trying to do.  Often *being*, is used in a participle phrase when a stronger two-clause construction sounds better.  Being late, he missed the bus.   Because he was late, he missed the bus.  On the other hand, sometimes you need *being* as part of the verb-phrase.  Which of the following best describe an individual who over-simplfies are rule of grammar.  The first one:  He is being lazy.  (Note the implied reference to some activity or action.) Or, the second one:  He is lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Well I agree, your instructor probably isn't the best, but right now let us just look at a workable alternative to being.

As he was of poor character,...